# Displaying xquery result

Tags: loops, formatting, xquery

I'm executing this function in xquery

```
     declare function local:f(){
        for $Restaurant in collection("Guide")/Restaurants/Restaurant
        return 
        <Restaurants>
        {local:f()/Nom}
        {local:f()/Adresse}
        {local:f()/Telephone}
        </Restaurants>
        };
```

this is what i'm getting as a result from the function :

```
<Restaurants>
   <Nom>La ferme Saint-Simon </Nom>
   <Nom>La Romantique </Nom>
   <Adresse>
        <Num> 6 </Num>
        <Rue> rue Saint Simon </Rue>
        <Zip> 75007 </Zip>
        <Ville> Paris </Ville>
    </Adresse>
   <Adresse>
        <Num> 8 </Num>
        <Rue> Avenue A.Piat </Rue>
        <Zip> 14000 </Zip>
        <Ville> Cabourg </Ville>
    </Adresse>
   <Telephone> 01 45 48 35 74 </Telephone>
   <Telephone> 01 45 48 35 75 </Telephone>
   <Telephone> 02 31 24 10 92 </Telephone>
</Restaurants>
```

I want to change the displaying  to something like this :

```
        <Restaurant>
        <Nom>La ferme Saint-Simon </Nom>
        <Adresse>
        <Num> 6 </Num>
        <Rue> rue Saint Simon </Rue>
        <Zip> 75007 </Zip>
        <Ville> Paris </Ville>
        </Adresse>
        <Telephone> 01 45 48 35 74 </Telephone>
        </Restaurant>

     <Restaurant>
        <Nom>La ferme Saint-Simon </Nom>
        <Adresse>
        <Num> 6 </Num>
        <Rue> rue Saint Simon </Rue>
        <Zip> 75007 </Zip>
        <Ville> Paris </Ville>
        </Adresse>
        <Telephone> 01 45 48 35 74 </Telephone>
        </Restaurant>
```

any help please i've just begun to learn xquery?

Comment: I don't see how your query can ever work - the function is infinitely recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Just reference to the variable $Restaurant (instead of the function local:f() itself) in your return:

```
declare function local:f(){
    for $Restaurant in collection("Guide")/Restaurants/Restaurant
    return 
    <Restaurants>
        {$Restaurant/Nom}
        {$Restaurant/Adresse}
        {$Restaurant/Telephone}
    </Restaurants>
    };
```